Where did Sergey Bulgakov write that the world cannot altogether fail?
In Chernobyl Prayer (or Voices from Chernobyl), one of the persons interviewed by Svetlana Alexievich says,

I found this by Father Sergey Bulgakov: 'as God most certainly created the world, the world cannot altogether fail'. And so we must 'valiantly endure history to the end'.

(Chernobyl Prayer, translated by Anna Gunin and Arch Tait. Penguin, 2016. Page 74.)
Sergei Bulgakov (1871–1944) was a Russian theologian and is not to be confused with that other Bulgakov.
I have been unable to find the exact source of that "quote" online. The possibility that the interviewee partially misremembers Bulgakov's words cannot be excluded. It is also possible that the two partial quotes stand further apart from each other than the passage in Alexievich's book suggest.
What I have found is the following passage from The Bride of the Lamb (1939), which does not come close enough:

God cannot fail to be the Creator, just as the Creator cannot fail to be God. The plan of the world's creation is co-eternal to God as is his own being in the Divine Sophia. In this sense (but only in this sense), God cannot do without the world, and the world is necessary for God's very being. And to this extent the world cannot be excluded in God's being in a certain sense.

This obviously does not say that the world cannot fail completely, but one might read the implication into it that if the world failed, that would be the failure of something "necessary for God's very being". That seems hardly compatible for the typical Christian view of God as a perfect being. However, I haven't found anything about valiantly enduring history to the end.
Could anyone identify the correct passage or passages in Sergey Bulgakov's work?

Isn't '… endure history to the end' a clear statement that history has an end?
Doesn't that necessarily imply not only that the world can, but that it ultimately must fail?

@RobbieGoodwin Maybe, but my question is merely about the source of the statement. I didn't comment on its validity.

Oh… I'm sorry I missed that. Where did your search engines let you down, please?

The quote from Alexievich in Russian:

Нашёл у отца Сергея Булгакова… «поскольку Бог создал мир наверняка, то
мир не может вовсе не удаться» и нужно «мужественно и до конца
претерпеть историю».

One part (“God made the world for certain”) comes from Sergei Bulgakov’s book Unfading Light: Contemplations and Speculations (translated by Thomas Allan Smith, PDF):

Бог создал мир наверняка, с безошибочной верностью, а не гадательною
только возможностью успеха или неуспеха, иначе бессильным и
несовершенным оказался бы его Создатель, потому что в таком случае
открылось бы нечто новое и неожиданное для Него самого, чего Он не мог
предвидеть.
God made the world for certain, with faultless fidelity and not with a
merely enigmatic possibility of success or failure; otherwise its
Maker would prove to be powerless and imperfect because in this case
something new and unexpected for him would have been revealed which he
himself was not able to foresee.

“the world cannot altogether fail” ("мир не может вовсе не удаться") relates to an earlier passage in the same book:

Мир не может вовсе не удаться, иначе говоря, тварный меон не может
разложиться обратно в укон, потонуть в беспредельности – άπειρον,
небытие не может волнами своими всплеснуть до неба и победить
божественную силу, однако в силу свободы своей мир может задерживаться
в состоянии меональности, не достигая высшей степени бытия.
It is not at all possible for the world not to succeed, or to say it
differently, the creaturely meon cannot decompose back into oukon,
sink into limitlessness — apeiron, nonbeing cannot splash its waves as
far as heaven and defeat divine power; however in virtue of its
freedom the world can linger in the state of meonality, not attaining
a higher level of being.

For the terms oukon and meon, the author gives the following explainer:

There can be two meanings of this not according to the sense of
creaturely nothing, to which two types of Greek negation correspond:
ou and mē [...] The
first corresponds to full negation of being — nothing, while the
second corresponds only to its nonmanifestation and nondefinition —
something. This second aspect of nonbeing, mē on, strictly speaking
refers rather to the realm of being. Mē on, as the possibility of
possibilities, is the universal mother of being, through  whose womb
all being passes […] Therefore the whole wealth and fullness of being
belong to the mē on, although potential and not manifested. One can
thus speak about it and about nonbeing only in relation to
already-manifested being, but not at all in the sense of emptiness,
the absence of being. Something is, the mē on exists, and between
nothing and something lies an incomparably greater gulf than between
something and a what, just as a greater gulf separates sterility from
pregnancy than pregnancy from birth. The mē on is pregnancy, the ouk
on is sterility. In order that a certain what could arise out of
nonbeing, ouk on must become mē on; it must overcome its emptiness and
be freed from its sterility.

The last part («мужественно и до конца претерпеть историю», 'valiantly endure history to the end') is from the last passage in Bulgakov’s Апокалипсис Иоанна (The Apocalypse of John):

Пророческая книга требует и пророческого к себе отношения и
восприятия, а вместе с тем, она и порождает его. Основная же и
единственная тема Апокалипсиса, как и его пророческая проповедь,
состоит в том, чтобы мужественно и до конца претерпеть историю, ибо
она есть и воцарение Христа Царя, путь к Царству Христову в мире,
совершившееся на кресте и совершающееся в крестных путях мира. «Се Аз
с вами есмь во вся дни до окончания века. Аминь» (Мф. XXVIII, 20).
A prophetic book requires a prophetic attitude, and at the same time,
gives rise to it. And the main and only theme of the Apocalypse, as
well as its prophetic sermon, is to endure history valiantly and to
the end, for it is also the accession of Christ the King, the path to
the Kingdom of Christ in the world, accomplished on the cross and
taking place in the ways of the cross in the world. "And behold, I am
with you always, to the end of the age" (Matthew 28:20).

